# How can I build javahg?

Tags: maven, javahg

I have made attempts to build 0.7 and later, but it always fails with the following message:

```
The build could not read 1 project -> [Help 1]

  The project com.aragost.javahg:javahg:0.7 (/home/<user>/DEV/NoBackup/javahg/pom.xml) has 1 error
Non-resolvable parent POM: Failure to find com.aragost.javahg:javahg-parent:pom:0.6 in http://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2 was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of central has elapsed or updates are forced and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 6, column 10 -> [Help 2]
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The newest version is 0.4 in [Maven Central](http://search.maven.org/#search%7Cga%7C1%7Cg%3A%22com.aragost.javahg%22%20AND%20a%3A%22javahg-parent%22)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Project has reference to parent which should be accessible in your local parent directory:

```
<parent>
        <groupId>com.aragost.javahg</groupId>
        <artifactId>javahg-parent</artifactId>
        <version>0.6</version>
        <relativePath>../javahg-parent</relativePath>
</parent>
```

please put https://bitbucket.org/aragost/javahg-parent in your environment, so you should have structure similar to:

```
/home/<user>/DEV/NoBackup/javahg
/home/<user>/DEV/NoBackup/javahg-parent - with proper version
```